# Border radius different with width and color - React Native

Tags: react-native

[image]

How can I fix this? And why is the radius different for the border and for the line?

```
<View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    width: '50%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
    paddingVertical: 24,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginVertical: 48,
    borderColor: '#cc0000',
    borderWidth: 0.2,
    borderRadius: 36,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Plz include the jsx and styling you used to get your current result ...

Comment: <View style={{ flex:1, width: "50%", justifyContent:'center', paddingHorizontal: 24 , paddingVertical: 24, backgroundColor: '#fff', marginVertical: 48, borderColor: '#cc0000", borderWidth: 0.2, borderRadius: 36, }}

Comment: Issue disappears for `borderWidth` >= 0.5 ... which is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happend for `borderWidth` < 0.5 ... you could either make it 0.5 or higher ... or use `borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth`

However it's better to go with `hairlineWidth` ... cause according to the docs:

> **hairlineWidth**
>
> This constant will always be a round number of pixels (so a line
> defined by it can look crisp) and will try to match the standard width
> of a thin line on the underlying platform. However, you should not
> rely on it being a constant size, because on different platforms and
> screen densities its value may be calculated differently.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that happens beacuse of the styling of the view where you have nested the picture. I don't know exactly how have you made what you show in the picture. If that's the case, try changing the diferent border properties of the outer view in order to match both borders.